# Use string formatting in Jython

Tags: java, jython

I am new in Jython.. I want to use the string formatting `str.format()` in Jython ([look here](http://www.jython.org/docs/library/string.html)).

If I try to use it like this:

```
testText = 'This is a {word}'
```

and later on

```
str.format(testText, word='test!')
```

the exception text is:

```
Error: exceptions.AttributeError instance of 'org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction' has no attribute 'format'
```

What do I have to add in the imports/classpath or anywhere?!

Thanks for your help!!

Kind regards

Comment: If I try this `'This is a {}'.format('test')` the error is `exceptions.AttributeError 'string' object has no attribute 'format'`

Comment: `'This is a {}'.format('test')` works fine in Jython 2.7. I suppose you use an older version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print "%(map_1)s  %(map_2)s" % {'map_1':'Hello','map_2':'World'}
```